# PHP libraries for handling nested sets in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

I read this article [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

At the end of this article, it writes about PHP libraries for handling nested sets in MySQL.

Does anyone know which PHP libraries he is talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propel 1.3/1.4 have very nice nested set support:  http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/wiki/Users/Documentation/1.3/Tree/NestedSet